# Matplotlib with PyQt - axes.clear() is very slow

Tags: python, charts, qt4, matplotlib, pyqt

I just want to plot a chart on my program. I need to use `axes.clear()` to draw a new chart for many times.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas   
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        # do something...
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
        # do something...

    def refresh(self):
        # FIXME: This method is very, very slow!!!
        self.axes.clear()

        # do something...
```

But it is very slow, It will hang my program for about 0.3s. Is it normal?

Comment: how much stuff do you have plotted on your axes when you clear it?

Comment: I just plotted some simple line chart. When a user clicked an item on the table, the chart will update. A user needs to click the table all the time.

Comment: You don't need to clear the complete axis, but it is usually sufficient to update the data of the chart.

Comment: I agree with @DavidZwicker, you should probably do this by updating your existing lines, but still find this a curious problem.

Comment: Should `axes.clear()` really be `self.axes.clear()`?  If I make this change, (and assume a minimal interface), `refresh` runs with no describable delay.  Can you post a minimal stand alone example that shows this display?

Comment: @tcaswell Yes, that right. Should be `self.axes.clear()`, it is just a typo, not in my code.

Comment: @David Zwicker But I need to plot different data, such as [0, 1, 2, 0], [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0]. How can I update exist axis?

Comment: `ln, = plot(...)`  then `ln.set_xdata(new_xdata)` and `ln.set_ydata(new_ydata)`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a rather old question but for all who are looking at this (like me) and still search a solution:

```
class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self):
        #...

        # get a reference to the line you want to plot
        self.line = self.axes.plot(xdata, ydata)

    def resfresh(self, xdata, ydata):
        # set the new data on one or more lines
        self.line.set_data(xdata, ydata)

        # redraw the axis (and re-limit them)
        axes.relim()
        axes.autoscale_view()

        # redraw the figure
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
```

I am using this with multiple subplots and multiple axes in one figure, this speeds up the process for me already quite a lot. I can't go further with stripping down my code because my plots are resizing the axis and the title is changing.

If you know that you **only** want the data to be repainted so the axis, the title and the range will stay the same you can strip this down even more:

```
def refresh(self, xdata, ydata):
    # "delete" the background contents, this is only repainting an empty
    # background which will look a little bit differently but I'm
    # fine with it
    self.axes.draw_artist(self.axes.patch)

    # set the new data, could be multiple lines too
    self.line.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    self.axes.draw_artist(self.line)

    # update figure
    self.fig.canvas.update()
    self.fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

I took a lot of information from [here](http://bastibe.de/2013-05-30-speeding-up-matplotlib.html). If you still want to improve the speed there may be a chance by using *blitting* but in the link posted before there is written:

> As it turns out, `fig.canvas.blit(ax.bbox)` is a bad idea since it leaks memory like crazy. What you should use instead is `fig.canvas.update()`, which is equally fast but does not leak memory.

I was also checking out the `matplotlib.animation` module but I have some buttons triggering the repaint (just like asked in the question) and I could not find out how to use the animations in my specific case.